# Potential Leak of an object allocated

Tags: objective-c

```
+ (WAController*) sharedWAController {

    @synchronized([WAController class]) {

        if (!_sharedWAController) 
            [[self alloc] init];

        return _sharedWAController;
    }
}
```

This is show in potential leak 
for `[[self alloc] init];`

Why its leak ?

Comment: Though I assume your question is "Why does this leak", there is no question here!

Comment: Opps i forget to type sorry james webster

Answer (score 3):

You never assign it to anything so it will just allocate a new object and leak it. To fix the leak and the incorrectly working code assign `_sharedWAController`

```
if (!_sharedWAController) 
    _sharedWAController = [[self alloc] init];
```

Comment: +1, but there's a lot of singleton implementation that make the assignation in `allocWithZone:`, but the static analyzer doesn't know that.

Comment: Where need to release _sharedWAController ?

Comment: Typically a singleton lives for the lifetime of the application, since you always have a reference to it there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

make it : `_sharedWAController = [[self alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (WAController*) sharedWAController {

    @synchronized([WAController class]) {

        if (!_sharedWAController)
        { 
            _sharedWAController = [[self alloc] init];
        }
        return _sharedWAController;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (CommonUtility*) sharedUtility {

    @synchronized([CommonUtility class]) {

        if (!_sharedUtility) 
            _sharedUtility = [[self alloc] init];

        return _sharedUtility;
    }
}


+ (id) alloc {

    @synchronized([CommonUtility class]) {

        _sharedUtility = [super alloc];
        return _sharedUtility;
    }
}
```

I try like this is this perfect.   But I allocated _sharedUtility object where i need to release. this In dealloc or autorelesae it.